# How to get Databricks notebook context of child notebook?

Tags: python, databricks

How would one go about getting the notebook context of a "child notebook" that is run using `%run`?

For example, I can get the notebook context of the current notebook using `json.loads(dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().toJson())`.

However, in a situation where I have 2 notebooks in the same folder, e.g. `notebook_1` and `notebook_2`, where `notebook_1` runs `notebook_2`:

```
# notebook_1
%run "./notebook_2"
```

```
# notebook_2
import json
context = json.loads(dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().toJson())
print(context)
```

Running `notebook_1` prints out `notebook_1`'s notebook context, but I actually want `notebook_2`'s context (e.g. to get `notebook_2`'s notebook ID). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Seems like a major short coming.  I am running into this same issue. I am trying to write logs that include the Notebook name and the command block.  Neither seem to be available.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `%run`, the notebook specified as its argument is really executed in the context of the caller notebook, that's why you're getting the `notebook_1` as context.  If it would be executed in a separate context, then it won't be possible to see function & variables definitions defined in `notebook_2` inside the `notebook_1`.

If you want to execute `notebook_2` in a separate context, then you need to use `dbutils.notebook.run` ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html#api))

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of `dbutils.notebook.run`, but the reason I am using `%run` instead is because I need to access functions / constants defined in `notebook_2`, and `dbutils.notebook.run` will not let me do such a thing.